# Does iterating the Union operator yield the empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

## Background

In elementary set theory the union is taught as a *binary operator* on two sets, which contains all the elements of both those sets.

$$
A = \{1,2,3\}\\
B = \{2,3,4\}\\
A\cup B = \{1,2,3,4\}
$$

In formal set theory this is generalized to a *unary operator* on one collection of sets, acting on each of the sets in that collection.

$$
\bigcup \{A,B\} = \{1,2,3,4\}
$$

And now we can apply the union operator to a collection of not only two, but an arbitrary number of sets …

$$
C = \{1,4,5\}\\
\bigcup \{A,B,C\} = \{1,2,3,4,5\}
$$

… even infinitely many.

$$
N_1 = \{1\} \land N_2 = \{2\} \land N_3 = \{3\} \land \cdots\\
\bigcup \{N_1,N_2,N_3,\dots\} = \{1,2,3,\dots\}
$$

We can even take the union of *a union* of sets.
$$
D = \{A,B\}\\
E = \{B,C\}\\
\bigcup \bigcup \{D,E\} = \bigcup \{A,B,C\} = \{1,2,3,4,5\}
$$

---

## Intermission

Advanced axiomatic set theory teaches the idea that *everything* is a set, and that the first set **guaranteed to exist** is the empty set. Other sets must be built from that starting point.

For example the natural number $0$ is the empty set $\emptyset$, the natural number $1$ is constructed as the singleton $\{0\}$, the natural number $2$ can be constructed as the pair $\{0,1\}$ (depending on the author), and so on.

The Axiom of Existence is the only axiom that guarantees that a set—the empty set—exists without the input of other sets. Other sets like ordered pairs and unions can only exist given an input.

The Axiom of Union states, “*given a collection of sets, there exists a set who owns any element of any set in that collection*” (as opposed to “all elements of all sets in the collection,” which would yield the intersection). The point is, a union set can exist, but the only way to create it is by giving, as an input, an existing set. That existing set could be a pair or a subset or even another union, which also require inputs; or it could be the empty set, which requires no previous set to exist. The bottom line is that the empty set is the foundation upon which all other sets are built.

---

## Question

So finally here’s my question. If you take the union of any set $S$, and then take the union of *that* set, and keep going, will this process eventually yield the empty set?

$$
\text{hypothesis: } \left(\forall S\right)\left(\bigcup\bigcup\cdots\bigcup S = \emptyset\right)
$$

Comment: I'm confused - why do you say "$\bigcup\emptyset$ does not exist"? It exists, and is $\emptyset$, since it's defined as "the set of all sets which are elements of some element of $\emptyset$" which is clearly empty. The *intersection* of the emptyset, $\bigcap\emptyset$, is the one which doesn't exist.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Well think about what $\bigcup S$ is saying: take all the elements of $S$, open them up, look at *their* elements, and put them all into a union set. But if there *are* no elements of $S$, then you cannot do this. However the union $\bigcup \{\emptyset\}$ does exist, and is in fact equal to $\emptyset$.

Comment: Don't think about what it's saying - it doesn't say anything. Think about the definition.

Comment: @chharvey, that's incorrect. The union of the emptyset is $\emptyset$ - $S$ having no elements does **not** make it undefined. Think about it this way: by definition, $a\in\bigcup S$ iff there is some $X\in S$ such that $a\in X$. It's clear by this definition that for no $a$ do we have $a\in\bigcup\emptyset$. Do you understand? (This is essentially an instance of *vacuous satisfaction*, similar to how e.g. "every element of the emptyset has 16 elements" is a true statement.)

Comment: 'The Axiom of Union states, “given a nonempty collection of sets..."'. Nope. Look it up: "Formally, the axiom of union states that for any set of sets..."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#5._Axiom_of_union

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yes thank you i'm working on it

Comment: I'm confused - why the downvote? The question seems fine (although I am a little put off by the subsequent issues around the union of the emptyset - but that's totally peripheral).

Answer (score 6):

First of all, “eventually” should be rigorously defined. Given a set $S$, and its union $\bigcup S$, and *that* union $\bigcup\bigcup S$, and so on… let’s say that at some point in that process you do get the empty set $\emptyset$. Then when you take its union, you’ll get the empty set again, and this process will go on forever. Suffice it to say that **this process will never stop**, because you can take the union of any set.

We’re looking for a set for which this process continues indefinitely, and fails to yield the empty set. It seems that an infinite set is a good candidate. Let’s try the set of Natural Numbers.

Use the method of construction given

\begin{align}
0 &= \emptyset\\
1 &= \{0\} = \{\emptyset\}\\
2 &= \{0,1\} = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\\
3 &= \{0,1,2\} = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}\\
&\cdots
\end{align}

and the set that contains all of these

$$\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$$

Now the union of $\mathbb{N}$ must contain any element in any set inside $\mathbb{N}$. That is, $\bigcup\mathbb{N}$ contains all the elements in $0$, all the elements in $1$, and in $2$, and in $3$, and so on. Keeping in mind that every set in $\mathbb{N}$ contains all the elements of the set “before” it, let’s start a list:

$$
\bigcup \mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}
$$

What do you know! This is exactly the set of Natural Numbers! The union of $\mathbb{N}$ really contains all the elements of $\mathbb{N}$.

$$
\bigcup \mathbb{N} = \mathbb{N}
$$

This is a perfect counterexample to the hypothesis. You can take as many unions as you want of $\mathbb{N}$ and you will always get $\mathbb{N}$.

$$
\bigcup\bigcup\cdots\bigcup \mathbb{N} = \mathbb{N} \not= \emptyset
$$

Comment: Your answer is generally nice, but it erroneously confirms OP's mistaken notion that "you cannot take the union of the empty set".

Comment: @MJD Note that the answerer *is* the OP . . . (On that note, if you knew the answer already then why did you ask the question?)

Comment: This example generalizes: If $\alpha$ is an **ordinal** then $\beta:=\bigcup \alpha$ is also an ordinal. We have $\beta\le \alpha$ and $\beta+1\ge \alpha$. In fact, $\beta+1=\alpha$ iff $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal. The Axiom of Infinity guarantees the existence of an infinite ordinal, hence also of a limit ordinal $>0$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Self-answering is far from being discouraged.

Comment: @NoahSchweber http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Re: your edit, are you aware of any system where taking the union of the emptyset is *not* allowed? Every system I'm aware of - ZFC, NF, NBG, KP, positive set theory, etc. - allows it, and I'd be very surprised to find one which didn't. As such, I find the "*in such some systems*" to be misleading.

Comment: " in some systems taking the union of the empty set is in fact possible. " What's an example of a formal set theory where this is not allowed?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from writing your own formal set theory in which this is not allowed. So long as the consequences are sound.

Comment: That's a really and truly ... words fail me. If you're interested in learning actual math then it's a hugely less than constructive attitude. I mean really - when you took calculus and you wrote $(t^2)'=t$ instead of $2t$ and it got marked wrong how far did you get explaining that this was your personal system?

Comment: @chharvey Actually, only the axiom of extensionality is needed to prove that the union of the emptyset is the emptyset (that is, the statement "if $A$ is an emptyset, then the union of $A$ is an emptyset" is provable from first-order logic alone, and then extensionality kicks in to say $A=\bigcup A$ if $A=\emptyset$). So I guess if you really want to work in a set theory without extensionality, then *maybe* you have a point (although I'm not even aware of any such set theory which doesn't allow the union of the emptyset), but this seems extremely silly. This still seems really misleading . . .

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I was hoping not to get into an argument about axiomatic systems but let's just say that the same thing was said when mathematicians started working with non-Euclidean geometry. Change the rules as much as you want, as long as your system is sound. Now as for my calculus class I accepted the premise that I was following the rules provided in standard mathematics (the textbook) and in that case $(t^2)'=t$ is of course not logically sound with those rules. It's not a matter of "right" and "wrong", it's a matter of "consistent" and "inconsistent". open your mind plz.

Comment: @chharvey Except you haven't given any example of a set theory in which the union of the emptyset is not defined. If you want to work in a different set theory, that's fine - but you need to actually articulate what its rules are at some point (note that the non-Euclidean geometers had no problem doing this). The gulf between "most systems" and "literally every system which has so far been studied seriously" is, to put it mildly, a bit large. Let me ask again: do you know of *any* system - including a system you've invented, perhaps - in which the union of the emptyset does not exist?

Comment: @NoahSchweber well wait a minute, why *can't* you invent a system which only restricts a definition or axiom? Most alternative systems (non-Euclidean geometry, nonstandard analysis) *expand* the original system on which they were built, and as a consequence, yield more interesting results. But I would think that *restricting* a system would be easier, because, at least in this case, you would just have to take out any references to $\bigcup\emptyset$, which by the way seems trivial because why would anyone need to do that calculation.

Comment: @chharvey Not really. Like I said repeatedly elsewhere, $\bigcup \emptyset$ is a shorthand for a formula. No axioms are needed to prove that "If $A$ is an emptyset, then $A$ is a union of itself." So I really don't see a way around this, short of barring the existence of the emptyset itself (which seems like a not-very-good fix) or changing how basic logic works (which, again, you can do - but at *some point* you have to actually do the work of articulating exactly what system you are using, and how it works). I reiterate for the $n$th time: do you know of any system where this happens?

Answer (score 3):

(This refers to an earlier version of the question, where it was said that $\bigcup\emptyset$ does  not exist.)

Your question has been answered. This is just a note to point out that there is no such caveat; there's no problem with $\bigcup\emptyset$. By definition $\bigcup S$ is the set of $x$ such that there exists $y\in S$ with $x\in y$; this applies perfectly well to the empty set and shows that $\bigcup\emptyset=\emptyset$.

As Noah points out, there's no such thing as $\bigcap\emptyset$. Why is that? Well, the definition is that $\bigcap S$ is the set of all $x$ such that $x\in y$ for *every* $y\in S$. If $x$ is anything at all then $x\in y$ for every $y\in\emptyset$, since there are no such $y$. So if $\bigcap\emptyset$ existed it would be the set of all sets, which leads to contradiction.

(No, there's no mention of this in the axioms. There's  no mention of $\bigcap$ at all in the axioms. It's a *theorem* that if $S$ is nonempty then $\bigcap S$ exists, and the proof doesn't work if $S=\emptyset$.)

---

The following is really part of a **comment** that doesn't fit very well into the comment box:

```
def WrongSum(data):
  res = data[0]
  for j = 1 to len(data)-1:
     res = res + data[j]
  return res

def RightSum(data):
  res = 0
  for j = 0 to len(data)-1:
     res = res + data[j]
  return res
```

They're the same, except when data is empty, in which case WrongSum crashes and RightSum gives the right answer.

Comment: A comment on the last paragraph (which is quite correct): there isn't even a symbol for $\bigcup$ or $\bigcap$ in the language of set theory. Expressions like "$\bigcup S$" are understood to be *shorthand* for a set satisfying an appropriate formula - e.g. "$\bigcup S$" is shorthand for a set $x$ satisfying "$\forall a(a\in x\iff \exists b(b\in S\wedge a\in b))$." Axioms are required for showing that such a set exists (Union in this case) or is unique (Extensionality in this case), but note that pure logic alone proves that $\emptyset$ is *a* union of $\emptyset$.

Comment: continuing the argument here… you may be right if in ZFC there is no mention of $\bigcap$ in the axioms, however you are equally free in an alternate system to provide an axiom for $\bigcap$ and then a *theorem* for $\subset$ as long as you accept proper classes.

Comment: @chharvey Given that you're so convinced that such a system must exist (and, presumably, be interesting/useful/some positive attribute), why don't you try to explicitly construct one?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Not that this is any of your business but I actually am working on a system of set theoretic axioms in computer programming. and as it turns out, the way that I've defined Union fails to work for empty sets, and instead of making an exception I simply restricted my definition to "the union of any *nonempty* set is …". As long as I don't attempt to calculate `union(emptyset)` I should be fine, right?

Comment: @chharvey Without knowing details of exactly what you did, I can't say. And based on your comment ("not that this is any of your business"), I'm sure you're not interested in discussing this further. It might be worth taking a glance at some other approaches to fully formalized set theory, though, which do indeed allow taking the union of the emptyset. And I might even suggest that the fact that this is causing an error, means that something else isn't working properly . . .

Comment: @chharvey " the way that I've defined Union fails to work for empty sets..." I bet you simply did it "wrong". Not wrong, but "wrong". Consider the analogous question of what the sum of no numbers at all should be. Compare WrongSum and RightSum in the edit I just made to my answer - they both work, except for empty data.